# Hide Empty Rows in a DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, wpfdatagrid

Good afternoon. I was able to populate data into a DataGrid control in vb.net. However, there are empty rows when you select different companies from the first dropdownlist. That is because the result of each selection was to output all reports in the datagrid, but only show the ones that are appropriate to the company, so those that aren't appropriate are left blank. However, I am stuck on how to hide those empty rows. i've looked at other sources, but none work. How do I hide the empty rows?

Here is my back-end:

```
        Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    DropDownList2.Items.Clear()

    'DropDownList2.Enabled = False
    'DropDownList3.Enabled = False
    'TextBox1.Enabled = False

    If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        Dim sConstr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ds17701ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(sConstr)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim valsql As String = ""
        Dim valsql1 As String = ""
        Dim ds_Reports As New DataSet()


        Dim parentitem As DataRow
        Dim childitem As DataRow

        'populates membership status once company selected
        valsql = "SELECT [CompanyID], [CompanyName], [MemberTypeID], [MembershipStatus], [GroupID]  FROM CompanyList WHERE COMPANYID = " & DropDownList1.SelectedValue


        valsql1 = "SELECT REPORTID, REPORTNAME, REPORTCODE FROM REPORTLIST WHERE ReportVisible = 1"
        valsql1 = valsql1 & ";SELECT c.ReportID, c.COMPANYID, rl.ReportName FROM  CompanyReportListTable c, ReportList rl WHERE c.reportid = rl.ReportID and rl.ReportVisible = 1 and CompanyID = " & DropDownList1.SelectedValue



        Using Conn
            Conn.Open()
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand(valsql, Conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm) 'da serves as the new sqldataadapter for my sqlcommand
            da.Fill(ds)
            'da.Fill(dt)

            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = valsql1
            da.Fill(ds_Reports)



        End Using

        ds_Reports.Relations.Add("CompanyReport", ds_Reports.Tables(0).Columns("ReportID"), ds_Reports.Tables(1).Columns("ReportID"))



        valGrid1.DataSource = ds_Reports.Tables(0)
        valGrid1.DataBind()




        For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(3).ToString = "M" Then
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "Member")
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, "Non-Member")
                TextBox1.Text = "M"
            Else
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "Non-Member")
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, "Member")
                TextBox1.Text = "NM"
            End If

        Next


    Else

        DropDownList2.Items.Clear()
        DropDownList3.Items.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text.ToString()
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

...and my front end for the datagrid. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        <asp:DataGrid ID="valGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0">

       <Columns>

           <asp:TemplateColumn>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DataGrid id="valgrid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderWidth="0" datasource='<%#Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("CompanyReport")%>'>
                    <Columns>
                         <asp:TemplateColumn>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# IIf((Container.DataItem("ReportID")).ToString().Equals(""), "false", "true")%>'/>

                                <asp:Label ID="lblRptName" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Container.DataItem("ReportName")).ToString())%>'></asp:Label>

                                 <asp:Label ID="lblReportID" Visible="false" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("ReportID") %>' />

                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateColumn>
                    </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>

            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateColumn>


       </Columns>

   </asp:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COLUMNS FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN IS NOT NULL
```